# R: plotting counts of substrings

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
gender <- c("F", "M", "M", "M", "M")
entourage <- c("YC; AD; EL", "YC", "AD; YC", "AD", "EL")
data <- data.frame(gender, entourage)
```

I want to plot the number of times substrings "YC", "AD", and "EL" occur in ggplot. I also want to plot the count of "YC" given that gender is "M".

Comment: So what exactly is the question here? Or the desired output? You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), not just a picture of data. Clearly show the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: `length(grep("YC", subset(data, gender=="M")$entourage))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the libraries:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

I believe the crux of the issue is getting your data into a `tidy` format -- or at least something more manageable for plotting. Create a tidy `data.frame`:

```
tidy.df <- data %>%
  mutate(ent = strsplit(as.character(entourage), "; ")) %>%
  unnest()

# head(tidy.df)
#   gender  entourage   ent
#   (fctr)     (fctr) (chr)
# 1      F YC; AD; EL    YC
# 2      F YC; AD; EL    AD
# 3      F YC; AD; EL    EL
# 4      M         YC    YC
# 5      M     AD; YC    AD
# 6      M     AD; YC    YC
```

Then you have lots of options for plotting. Look at examples for `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` or perhaps `geom_bar(position = "dodge")`.

```
ggplot(tidy.df, aes(x = ent, fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image: Plot]